# Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_even()

Tags: functions

I am editing an older wordpress theme, and I am receiving this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_even()`.

```
    <?php if($blog_post_query->have_posts()): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        $blog_count = 0;
        while($blog_post_query->have_posts()): $blog_post_query->the_post(); $blog_count++;//<!-- error line -->
            $style = ( is_even( $blog_count ) ) ? 'even' : 'odd';?>
            <li class="<?php echo $style; ?>">
                <h2><?php te_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-content/content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>fit-news" class="button button-blue pull-right">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `is_even` function isn't defined. You can either make sure it's defined in the themes function or replace it:

**To replace it, you can use**

```
$style = ( $blog_count % 2 ) ? 'even' : 'odd';
```

**or define the is_even funtion**

```
function is_even( $blog_count ) {
    if ( $blog_count % 2 )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My friend, I think the only reason this hasn't been accepted is you haven't used scope `{}` after if `( $blog_count % 2 )`, else is perfect.

Comment: This should work without the brace, you can test it yourself. Thanks for the heads up though.